# is there a node.js package to embed Google Analytics charts into a web page

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am building a Node.js Analytics dashboard that includes internally generated data, and would like to add Charts from our Google Analytics. 
1/ What is the right Google Analytics API to do so
2/ Is there a node.js package to embed the chart itself (rather than retrieving the data from GA and then having to build the chart myself)?

Comment: I answered below, but you should really demonstrate more research effort before bringing a question to stackoverflow. Look over the [faq](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq) to get a better understanding of what makes a good question here.

Answer (score 1):

While not specifically Node.js, this is now possible with client-side JavaScript and Google's [Embed API](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/). That page also has well documented tutorials for building a [basic dashboard](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/basic-dashboard/), [interactive charts](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/interactive-charts/) and more.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the [**Core Reporting API**](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/) to pull data, and you could try [**Google Chart Tools**](https://developers.google.com/chart/) for creating your graphs.

Comment: I am aware of these APIs and my question was specifically asking about getting avoiding the heavy lifting of "_retrieving the data from GA and then having to build the chart myself_". I was hoping there is a way to get the charts produced by Google Analytics directly - e.g. as a widget that can be embedded in my page

Answer (score 0):

Check out [EmbeddedAnalytics](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com).

While not a node.js solution, we are a 3rd party solution (using the Core Reporting) designed specifically so that you can avoid the heavy lifting of "*retrieving the data from GA and then having to build the chart myself*" as you have said yourself.

The process is very simple.

1. Grant us authorization to access your GA Data via the API.
2. Design your chart (all kinds of formatting are available).
3. Embed an `<iframe>` tag where the chart is to display.